# python requests getting unauthenticated or error 401

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to request post to my web server a notification but it shows error 401. 
I already tested my API key in postman and it works but when I used it in python it shows error 401 or error:unathenticated.

Here's my code

```
import requests

req = requests.post('https://sampleweb.com/api/v1/devices/1/notifications', 
    json={ 'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9',
    "notification": { "message":"hey", "level": 4}})

print(req.json())

file = open("alert_content.txt", "a") 
file.write(req.text + "\n")
file.close()
```

Comment: have you tried changing `json=` to `data=` ?

Comment: it doesn't work either.

Comment: hmm, have you tried adding a header?

Comment: I've already solved my problem. I'm gonna post the answer below. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've searched and read some documentations regarding to my question and I already solved it. Here's the code.

```
import requests

url = "https://sampleweb.com/api/v1/devices/1/notifications"
auth = {'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ',
'content-type':'application/json'}
params  = {"notification":{"message":message,"level":level}}


req = requests.post(url, headers= auth, json = params)

print(req.json())

file = open("alert_content.txt", "a") 
file.write(req.text + "\n")
file.close()
```

The authorization needs the content-type and the params or parameters needed to be in json format. Now it works.